# How Ants know about Earthquake?

Tags: physiology, biophysics, ant

How does an ant know about Earthquake is it because of an organ or due to other factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they may not sense Earthquake by an organ but due to other reasons. This may be any other physical factors which can be measured.

> **"...There is therefore
>   little reason to believe that these ants react to earthquake
>   precursors other, perhaps, than those that may affect colonies
>   directly, by altering physical variables that can be directly measured
>   by other means..."**

Fascinating though the behavior and physiology of ants may be, they cannot be employed as reliable predictors or even sensors of earthquakes.

Source: [Shaken, not stirred: a serendipitous study of ants and earthquakes](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/208/16/3103.long)

Comment: @Chris Is it better now?